# Benefit on javascript which I do not understand

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf, validation

Well, a respected site wrote about javascript advantages and one of the **big** advantages was:

> JavaScript has validations on client side, so the server itself is less loaded

Sounds fine.
However, what is different in C# WPF\Windows Forms for example?

Same goes here...you can do many validations check on the form itself..
Then why is it that they talk on **JavaScript** as if it is really special and major?

Could you tell me what they meant by telling this advantage?

Comment: I suppose this refers to the ability to check input client-side before the form is submitted which requires reloading the page for bad input. You still need to validate server side though.

Comment: C# and Windows Forms either run on the server side or they generate javascript (I don't know, i'm not a Windows developer).  *However* I'm of the opinion you can _never_ trust the client. If you have no validation on the server side then a nefarious person can send bad data by simply turning off their javascript.  Javascript's advantage is to give instant feedback to your user.  It can reduce load by doing a pre-validation for your normal customers who just enter bad data.  Its a supplement, not a replacement.

Comment: @Cfreak "I'm of the opinion you can *never* trust the client." That's not an opinion, that's a well-established fact. :)

Answer (score 2):

Validation on the client side is both an advantage and a disadvantage.

It's an advantage because it reduces requests to the server that contain invalid data.  With fewer requests to handle, the server needs fewer resources.  This differs from C# specifically in that C# validation code runs on the web server.

However, it's also a disadvantage in that you need to write the same validations on the server side "just-in-case".  You have no guarantee that data submitted to your server actually went through the javascript validation!  People can post data to your server endpoints directly, using tools like Postman or Fiddler, bypassing everything you've written in javascript.

Comment: Just use Node.js and re-use your validation logic ;)